# How do I convert hex (buffer) to IPv6 in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, hex, ip, ipv6

I have a buffer that contains a hex representation of an IPv6 address.
How exactly do I convert it to an actual IPv6 representation?

```
// IP_ADDRESS is a buffer that holds the hex value of the IPv6 addr.

let IP_ADDRESS_HEX = IP_ADDRESS.toString('hex'); 
// 01000000000000000000000000000600
```

I don't actually mind using a simple lib if it offers a conversion function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your IP_ADDRESS_HEX always has the same size, you can do the following. If not you need to pad the string as well.

```js
'01000000000000000000000000000600'
    .match(/.{1,4}/g)
    .join(':')

// "0100:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0600"
```

You can also shorten certain blocks, but this is not a necessity eg `ffff:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000` would become `ffff::` but both are valid.

If you still want it full spec you can do it like this

```js
'01000000000000000000000000000600'
  .match(/.{1,4}/g)
  .map((val) => val.replace(/^0+/, ''))
  .join(':')
  .replace(/0000\:/g, ':')
  .replace(/:{2,}/g, '::')

// "100::600"
```

Comment: Ah Thanks! Looks like I had understood my problem wrong.  My hex is already in IPv6. I just had to represent it in the specific format.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I really answer to your question, but to convert the string `IP_ADDRESS_HEX` to an IPv6 address representation, I would use String.slice() to split `IP_ADDRESS_HEX` in 8 groups and use String.join() to add the ":" between these groups.

```
var IP_ADDRESS_HEX = "01000000000000000000000000000600";
var i = 0;
var a = [];
while (i != 8) {
    a[i] = IP_ADDRESS_HEX.slice(i * 4, (i * 4) + 4);
    i++;
}
result = a.join(":");
```

Of course, it only works when `IP_ADDRESS_HEX` has exactly 32 characters.