# How to find start and End IP address for CIDR in snowflake

Tags: ip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The Parse_IP is giving the result in hexadecimal formate.but i need output in ip address format.
for example
For cidr 2c0f:eb00:400::/40 (jw.org)
ip_start should be - 2c0f:eb00:400::
ip_end  will be - 2c0f:eb00:4ff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff

Answer (score 0):

Using [PARSE_IP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_ip.html):

> Returns a JSON object consisting of all the components from a valid INET (Internet Protocol) or CIDR (Classless Internet Domain Routing) IPv4 or IPv6 string.

The formatting could be perfromed via JavaScript UDF.
Function body: [How do I convert hex (buffer) to IPv6 in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57077959/5070879):

```
create or replace function format_ip(IP STRING)
  returns STRING
  language javascript
AS 
$$
 return IP.match(/.{1,4}/g)
  .map((val) => val.replace(/^0+/, ''))
  .join(':')
  .replace(/0000\:/g, ':')
  .replace(/:{2,}/g, '::');
$$;
```

Query:

```
SELECT PARSE_IP('2c0f:eb00:400::/40', 'CIDR')AS res,
       FORMAT_IP(res:hex_ipv6_range_start::string) as ip_start,
       FORMAT_IP(res:hex_ipv6_range_end::string) as ip_end;
/*
RES
{    "family": 6,    
      "hex_ipv6": "2C0FEB00040000000000000000000000",
      "hex_ipv6_range_end": "2C0FEB0004FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF",
      "hex_ipv6_range_start": "2C0FEB00040000000000000000000000",
      "host": "2c0f:eb00:400::",
      "ip_fields": [      739240704,      67108864,      0,      0    ],
      "ip_type": "cidr",
      "netmask_prefix_length": 40,
      "snowflake$type": "ip_address"  
}
         
IP_START    2C0F:EB00:400::
IP_END      2C0F:EB00:4FF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF
*/
```

Comment: Is there any way we can get IP start and IP end without using Parse_IP.once we get IP start and IP end ,i have to split the IP start and IP end into start low and high ,end low and high as below.cidr 2c0f:eb00:400::/40 (jw.org)
ip_start - 2c0f:eb00:400::
ip_end - 2c0f:eb00:4ff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
ip_start_high = ::2c0f:eb00:400:0 -> 3175014647619125248
ip_end_high = ::2c0f:eb00:4ff:ffff -> 3175014647635902463
ip_start_low = 0:0:0:0 -> 0
ip_start_high = ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff -> 18446744073709551615

Comment: parse_Ip is not working for the below legit CIDR.  'ff02:0:0:0:0:1:ff00::/104'.Is there any other way we can convert this to IPV6 CIDR .It is working for either 'ff02:0:0:0:0:1:ff00:0/104' or 'ff02::1:ff00:0/104'.

Comment: Find a solution with a Java UDF in the meantime: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68188162/132438 (I filed SNOW-374145 internally - this is indeed a valid ipv6 range)